# How do I make the console keep prompting the user for input until the user enters a positive integer in C?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{   
    printf("Give me the length of your shower in minutes: \n");
    int x = GetInt();
    int b = x*12;

    if (x <= 0)
        {
        printf("Please give me a valid input.\n");   
        }

    else           
        printf("In %i minutes you consumed %i bottles of water!\n", x, b);
}
```

This is my code for an algorithm that takes minutes of a shower and converts it to bottles of water used.

I've tried to write it in different ways and even using "scanf" but nothing has worked. The code works fine except that when the user inputs something that is zero or a negative number it just prints "That is not a positive integer." before the program just shuts down. I need it loop back and get another input from the user until they return something positive. I've tried a couple do/while and for loops but I don't think I'm doing it right. Could someone please help a rookie coder out?

Comment: You need to use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will simply repeat the prompt until a valid value is entered, then print he result:

```
int main(void)
{   
    int x = 0 ;

    do
    {
        printf( "Give me the length of your shower in minutes:\n" ) ;
        x = GetInt() ;

    } while( x <= 0 ) ;

    int b = x * 12 ;
    printf( "In %i minutes you consumed %i bottles of water!\n", x, b ) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where "do something else" means also leave the loop :p.

```
while (true) {
    x = GetInt();
    if (x <= 0) {
        printf("Please give me a valid input.\n");
    } else {
        // do something else
        // and leave
        break;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need "loop" to repeat the code, in c, there is `for`, `while`, `do while`. Such as:

```
while (true) {
    x = GetInt();
    if (x <= 0) {
        printf("Please give me a valid input.\n");
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```